# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Points' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, parsing, parse-error, php-parse-error

I'm trying to make a form that updates a datebase but it gives me an error. Do you have any idea what it could be from?
The error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Points' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   D:\2013.1\xampp\htdocs\ranklist_get.php on line 9

**welcome.html**

```
<body>
<form action="ranklist_get.php" method="get">
Skype: <input type="text" id="Skype"><br>
Points: <input type="number" id="Points"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ranklist_get.php** ****The solved code by Abhik Chakraborty :)***

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Points='".$Points."' WHERE Skype='".$Skype."'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Points="$Points";
WHERE Skype="$Skype""); 

to 

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Points='".$Points."' WHERE Skype='".$Skype."'");
```

Comment: Thanx, but now it gives me these errors
Notice: Undefined variable: Points in D:\2013.1\xampp\htdocs\ranklist_get.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined variable: Skype in D:\2013.1\xampp\htdocs\ranklist_get.php on line 9

Comment: how u are getting the values before using in sql ?

Comment: The values are being inputed in the welcome.html and then they are being updated in the sql database by ranklist_get.php

Answer (score -1):

use a valid syntax. it should have been

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Points = '" . $Points . "' WHERE Skype = '" . $Skype . "'");
```